# Normalizr : Only add item to items array if the id is present

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, normalizr

How to prevent adding value to entities or pushing it to the `items` array?

I tried returning `undefined` from `idAttribute`, but still, it pushes the `undefined` in the `items` array and also adds a key named `undefined` in the entities.

```
const getGuid = (entity: any) => {
  if (entity.enclosure) {
    if (entity.guid) {
      return entity.guid
    } else if (entity.enclosure.url) {
      return entity.enclosure.url
    }
  }
}

const fetchPodcastRssEpisodeSchema = new schema.Entity(
  'episodes',
  {},
  {
    idAttribute: getGuid,
    processStrategy: (entity, parent, _key) => {
      const itunes = entity.itunes || {}
      const enclosure = entity.enclosure || {}

      const image =
        itunes.image ||
        (parent.image && parent.image.url) ||
        (parent.itunes && parent.itunes.image)

      return {
        artist: parent.title,
        content: entity.content,
        durationSeconds: utils.transformDurationToSecs(itunes.duration),
        guid: getGuid(entity),
        image,
        pubDate: entity.isoDate,
        title: entity.title,
        url: enclosure.url,
      }
    },
  }
)
```

The item should only be added if it returns a valid value from `idAttribute`. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: could you show the code for this?

Answer (score 0):

update with

```
const getGuid = (entity: any) => {
   if (entity && entity.enclosure) {
     if (entity && entity.guid) {
       return entity.guid
     } else if (entity && entity.enclosure && entity.enclosure.url) {
       return entity.enclosure.url
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: This could be a better way to write it, but it still doesn't solve the issue i.e undefined will be added in the items array

Comment: I think the explanation is not clear. Let me explain again. I don't want an item with a value `undefined`. Here, if entity && entity.enclosure is false then undefined will be returned which will be pushed into the items array which I don't want.